# UnmodifiableRandomAccessList exception converting collection from Java to Scala

Tags: scala

I have the following call to a Java function in my Scala code:

```
 val result = javaObject.javaFunction().asInstanceOf[ArrayList[ArrayList[String]]]
```

I convert the result from `ArrayList[ArrayList[String]]` to `Seq[Seq[String]]`:

```
import collection.JavaConverters._
val result2 = result.asScala.toSeq.map( _.asScala.toSeq)
```

This compiles, but on execution I get:

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList cannot be cast to
>   java.util.ArrayList

Why does this happen and how to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried `asInstanceOf[List[List[String]]]` instead of the overly specific `ArrayList[ArrayList[String]]`?

Comment: I just tried, it says: `value asScala is not a member of List[List[String]]`

Comment: I of course meant `java.util.List[java.util.List[String]]`, I hoped it was clear from the context...

Comment: yes, that worked!

Comment: Are you sure you need to cast at all? What is the return type of `javaFunction()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've guessed the type wrong, and got a class cast exception.
Just use a less restrictive type in the `asInstanceOf`:

```
 val result = javaObject.javaFunction().
   asInstanceOf[java.util.List[java.util.List[String]]]
```

Because there is an implicit conversion method

```
asScalaBufferConverter[A](l: List[A]): AsScala[Buffer[A]]
```

in `JavaConverters`, the `java.util.List` type is enough to make the `asScala` conversion available.